# Data not inserting into database table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

```
string constr = "Data Source =. ;Initial Catalog =reg ;Integrated Security=true;";
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(constr);
conn.Open();
string sql = "Insert Into Course Values(@CustomerFName,@CustomerLName,@Email ,@PhoneNo ,@CourseName);";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerFName", txthrfn.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerLName", txthrln.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txthrem.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PhoneNo", txthrmob.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CourseName", ddlhr.SelectedItem.ToString());

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. So, what is your problem? This code isn't working? You get any exception or error message? Your `Course` table has 5 columns only? Please read [FAQ], [ask] and [help]. By the way, use `using` statement to dispose your `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand`

Comment: mr.soner .. the inserting process is done correctly ,, but the problem is without data ,, my field name is correct ,,

Comment: @AhmadOShakour your title says it is not inserting, you should say that it insert null values

Comment: @AhmadOShakour _the inserting process is done correctly_ Your title says the opposite? o.O You have a problem when you try to insert some `null` values? Are your columns `nullable`? On which column exactly you have a problem?

Comment: sorry ,, it's my fault , no it's not nullable,all of them  ,,so can you help me plz?

Comment: @AhmadOShakour how can someone help you without any information about your problem?

Comment: what is the needed info?
here is my sql code
 create table Course(
CustomerID     int  identity(1,1)  primary key ,
CustomerFName  nvarchar(50)  not null ,
CustomerLName  nvarchar(50) not null ,
Email          nvarchar(50) not null ,
PhoneNo        int          not null,
CourseName     nvarchar(50) not null
);

Comment: Very hard to determine what the problem is. Is your connection good? Also, try adding the ` to the `TABLE` name, "Insert Into \`Course Values\`"

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Answer (score 1):

I'd try something like:

```
    string constr = "Data Source =. ;Initial Catalog =reg ;Integrated Security=true;";
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(constr);
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    { MessageBox.Show(err.Message); }
    string sql = "Insert Into Course(CustomerFName,CustomerLName,Email,PhoneNo,CourseName) Values(@CustomerFName,@CustomerLName,@Email,@PhoneNo,@CourseName)";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerFName", txthrfn.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerLName", txthrln.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txthrem.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PhoneNo", txthrmob.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CourseName", ddlhr.SelectedItem.ToString());

    try { cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); }
    catch (Exception err)
    { MessageBox.Show(err.Message); }

    try { conn.Close(); }
    catch (Exception err)
    { MessageBox.Show(err.Message); }
```

At least that way you'll know what's wrong.

Note : Can't comment on your question yet (not enough rep).